# Match anything in Rails (Activerecord) WHERE condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

When no parameters are passed to the following I want to be able to select all Articles.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :filter_by, lambda 
  { 
    |*args| {:conditions => [(args.first || 'id') + " = ?", (args.second || '*is_anything*')]} 
  }

end
```

For example, `Article.filter_by()` should be the same as `Article.all` . What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible way to do it, I'm struggling to see what you're trying to do. You could use "IS NOT NULL" or ">0"

Comment: Just wondering why you need to create this functionality?

Comment: @Ant ... for convenience. I could then do Articles.filter_by('author', 'Paul').filter_by('tag', 'rails')

Comment: @Zack Ok, well if it fits your needs then Jeff's solutions below looks good :-) However, in my opinions using the standard syntax seems much cleaner: Article.where(:author => "Paul", :tag => "rails")

Comment: In addition to Ants comment you could chain conditions together to kind of acheive the same result. Article.where(:author=>"Paul").where(:tag=>"Rails")  Providing you're using rails 3. You are using Rails 3 aren't you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
  named_scope :filter_by, lambda 
  { 
    |*args| {:conditions => (args.nil? || args.empty?) ? nil : [(args.first || 'id') + " = ?", (args.second || '*is_anything*')]} 
  }
```